# PDOException could not find driver using Propel v2

Tags: php, mysql, apache, propel

I've installed Propel correctly according the installation manual (http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html). I checked that PHP was loading pdo_mysql driver so I made a phpinfo() test and It showed that everything was correct. Nevertheless, when I made a simple Query using Propel, as showing below:

```
<?php
//define('BASE_PATH', '/Users/jvarela/Development/Crack/Crack-Server');
define('BASE_PATH', '/Library/WebServer/Documents');
ini_set('include_path', BASE_PATH.':'.ini_get('include_path').':'.BASE_PATH.'/propel/vendor/propel/src');

spl_autoload_extensions(".php"); // comma-separated list
spl_autoload_register();

// setup the autoloading
require_once 'propel/vendor/autoload.php';

// setup Propel
require_once 'propel/vendor/generated-conf/config.php';

echo 'All ok, for now...';

    $a = new JugadorQuery();
    $a->findPK(1);

?>
```

I'm receiving the error below.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/propel/vendor/propel/src/propel/runtime/connection/connectionfactory.php on line 44
( ! ) PDOException: could not find driver in /Library/WebServer/Documents/propel/vendor/propel/src/propel/runtime/connection/pdoconnection.php on line 50
```

The strange thing is that if I just create a PDO object like the example below, I get no error and It connects to the Database properly

```
$test = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost","user","pass")
```

Have anyone got the same error or known if I made a mistake installing Propel v2.0 properly? Thank you

PD: I'm using Apache v2.2, PHP v5.4 and MySQL v 5.6

Regards.

Comment: Guess you have a typo somewhere in the configuration. Try to debug/var_dump arguments passed to `parent::_construct` at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/master/runtime/lib/connection/PropelPDO.php#L153

Comment: Yes MArc, actually the propel.xml file that I copied from the tutorial in the project site had a syntax error that was firing a PDOException. The driver attribute had a space at the beginning. I updated the solution in the wiki and now It is fixed in case someone had the aame problem. Thank you.

Comment: You mean at our website propelorm.org? Can you show me where exactly?

Comment: Actually I can't because I've already fixed it in the wiki (via the Github project) and they accepted and uploaded it, so now the website is showing it right. It was in the propel configuration file, the XML example in: http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html had a space at the beginning in the dns attribute.